# Why is the div not a the top of the page?

Tags: html

In this code I create a div for my navigation bar. The div is showing correctly, however has space on the top-padding and the left-padding when the padding is at 0. Anyone know why? thanks.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Blitz</title>


<style>
.Navigationbar{
background-color:#2DDEDE;
height:auto;
border:none;
}

.Navigationbar li{
display:inline;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>


<div class="Navigationbar">
<ul>

<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Featured</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
</ul>
<h1><center>Blitz</center></h1>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show you setting the padding to 0; are you doing that? It could be margins on the div. It could also be that the UL has padding/margins on the top; check for that as well. And the entire body might have margins, you'll want to set those to 0 as well.

Comment: add margin:0!important and padding:0!important to html, body{}

Comment: Oh yes, of course! Thanks folks.

Comment: Not sure he would have to use `!important` unless there was some other CSS effecting his own (which it doesn't look like it)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oofj1sL0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body tag has 8 pixels margin.
Can be removed like this:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Blitz</title>


<style>
.Navigationbar{
background-color:#2DDEDE;
height:auto;
border:none;
}

.Navigationbar li{
display:inline;
}
.nomargin
{
    margin: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body class="nomargin">


<div class="Navigationbar">
<ul>

<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Featured</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
</ul>
<h1><center>Blitz</center></h1>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the body margin to 0 as well:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add to your code

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
```